# How to auto request focus to a text field when navigated to a composable in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-text

I want the keyboard to pop up by an auto requesting focus on a text field in jetpack compose when the user navigates to a composable. As of now, this is what I have tried but it doesn't seem to work

```
val feedbackContent = remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue()) }
val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }

OutlinedTextField(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .clickable {
                        focusRequester.requestFocus()
                    }
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .focusRequester(focusRequester)
                    .focusable()
)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }
val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current

OutlinedTextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = { text = it},
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .focusRequester(focusRequester)
        .onFocusChanged {
            if (it.isFocused) {
                keyboardController?.show()
            }
        }
)

LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    focusRequester.requestFocus()
}
```

Comment: Hi @Gabriele I also tried your another answer, however neither of them seem to be working. I can definite see that the outlinedText is getting focused, however the keyboard is not showing nor there is a cursor inside. Is there anything else need to be done to achieve OP's effect? Many thanks.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti, is there a reason to use `DisposableEffect` in case `onDispose{}` isn't actually needed? Will `LaunchedEffect` be sufficient in those cases?

Comment: this does not work

Comment: should use it.hasFocus instead of isFocused. Atleast that is what worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can try this(I tested this and it works):

```
val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }
val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current

LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    focusRequester.requestFocus()
}

OutlinedTextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = { text = it},
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .focusRequester(focusRequester)
)
```