# How to open a BasicTextField focused with blinking cursor in it?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-compose-textfield

I have a `BasicTextField` in one of my views. I am showing the soft keyboard by default and when I start typing letters on the keyboard, nothing is shown in the `BasicTextField`, since it has no cursor.

To make my keyboard actions visible, I have to tap into the TextField, to make the cursor visible. Now, whenI tap on the keyboard, I see the result in the `BasicTextField`.

How can I open the BasicTextField with an active blinking cursor in it?

EDIT: the [proposed solution from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68269353/5102206) did not work for me

```
val focusRequester = FocusRequester()
val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current

//..

    .focusRequester(focusRequester)
    .onFocusChanged {
        if (it.isFocused) {
            keyboardController?.show()
        }
    }
```

Did neither activated the cursor nor made the keyboard appear. In addition to that

```
DisposableEffect(Unit) {
    focusRequester.requestFocus()
    onDispose { }
}
```

leads to a crash:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException:
> FocusRequester is not initialized. Here are some possible fixes:
>
> ```
>    1. Remember the FocusRequester: val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }
>    2. Did you forget to add a Modifier.focusRequester() ?
>    3. Are you attempting to request focus during composition? Focus requests should be made in
>    response to some event. Eg Modifier.clickable { focusRequester.requestFocus() }
>
>     at androidx.compose.ui.focus.FocusRequester.requestFocus(FocusRequester.kt:54)
> ```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68268544/how-to-auto-request-focus-to-a-text-field-when-navigated-to-a-composable-in-jetp) answer your question?

Comment: @PhilipDukhov I changed the OP

Comment: Why don't you follow "possible fixes"? Especially the first one.

Comment: @PhilipDukhov The link you provided exactly has 1 answer from GabrieleMariotti and I applied that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got it working:

```
val focusRequester = FocusRequester()

//..

.focusRequester(focusRequester)
```

and instead of

```
DisposableEffect(Unit) {
    focusRequester.requestFocus()
    onDispose { }
}
```

I used

```
LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    focusRequester.requestFocus()
}
```

Comment: What is isFocused in the latest block in your answer ?

Comment: Just a boolean flag under which condition you want to focus. Remove if you want to focus under any condition. I removed irritating leftover